# Weird Javascript Outputs

Tags: javascript, arrays, stack, undefined

I have this Javascript object, data, that I am trying to add to a stack. However, I am getting some really weird errors. Such as,

```
var data = {
    "name" : "unknown",
    "id": 1,
    "children": [ 
        {
            "name": "test",
            "id": 2,
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "test",
                    "id": 4,
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "test",
            "id": 3
        }
    ]
};
var stack = [data];
console.log(stack); // output: undefined
while (stack.length > 0) {
    console.log(stack); // output: undefined
    var pop = stack.pop()
    console.log(stack); // output: undefined
}
```

The only thing I can image is that there is some sort of issue with the pointer to the stack object when the while loop get involved.

Interestingly enough, when I take the while loop out of the mix or add an index to the stack, normal values are returned. For instance,

```
var stack = [data];
console.log(stack); // [Object ... ] with the correct data
```

or

```
var stack = [data];
console.log(stack[0]); // [Object ... ] with the correct data
while (stack.length > 0) {
    console.log(stack[0]); // [Object ... ] with the correct data
    var pop = stack.pop()
    console.log(stack); // [] as it should be...
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `console = {}; console.log = function() {};` Try writing `delete console` in your console.

Comment: With my jsFiddle log function everything working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/ifch0o1/422jfv93/1/ It seems to be a console issue.

Answer (score 1):

If someone overrides the console object with custom functions, eg: `console = {log: function() {}};` it would seem that `console.log()` would output undefined.

Consider this:

```
console = {log: function() {}};
console.log(1); // undefined
delete console; // true
console.log(1); // 1
```

In Chrome you can delete the console object as many times as you want, it will always be there, but it will remove any custom defined object.

Comment: This is probably it, it's common to override console in hindsight to send logs to the server (although it's not a good practice).

Comment: @Bimper If you are running in a production server and your minifier / concatenater doesn't take care of removing `console.log`'s it can make sense to override the `console` object.